# nested list average

Tags: list, lisp

Hi everyone I have implemented a solution to find the average for a nested list. So I was wondering if you could think of a better solution or any possible errors with mine cheers.

```
; takes a nested list and return a flattened list
(defun flatten-list (list)
  (cond 
     ((null list) list)  
     ((atom list) (list list))  
     ((list (first list))
            (append (flatten-list (first list))
                    (flatten-list (rest  list)))) 

   (t      
            (append (list (first list))
                          (flatten-list (rest  list))))
   ))

;takes a flattened list and return the sum of the numbers
(defun sum-list (list)
  (cond ((null list)
         0)    
        (t
         (+ (first list) (sum-list(rest list))))
        ))

;uses the flatten-list and nested-average to find the average
(defun nested-average (list)  
  (sum-list  (flatten-list list))
  (defvar flat-lis)
  (setf flat-list (flatten-list list))
  (/ (sum-list  flat-list) (length flat-list)
  ))
```

Comment: did you try to run it? Did you test it with input? Did you compile it?

Comment: of course i did, it is compiling and running all of my tests, but i am new to lisp and i am looking for new and more elegant solutions.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the better solution...

```
(defun tree-average (tree)
  (labels ((%tree-average
            (branch sum visited)
            (cond
             ((consp branch)
              (multiple-value-call
               #'%tree-average (cdr branch)
               (%tree-average (car branch) sum visited)))
             ((numberp branch)
              (values (+ sum branch) (1+ visited)))
             (t (values sum visited)))))
    (multiple-value-call #'/ (%tree-average tree 0 0))))
```

Well, if you ask.

Comment: (multiple-value-call #'/ (%tree-average tree 0 0))

Answer (score 1):

The first function contains unreachable code. That code will never be used. The documentation string is also wrong, because it does not really describe what the function does.

The second function is better written using `REDUCE`.

The third function needs to be rewritten. The value of the first form is not used. Using `DEFVAR` and `SETF` is wrong.

Comment: 1 - What do you mean that the first function contains unreachable code that will never be used. 2-how can i use reduce for the second function and 3 - are you saying that it is better to use (defvar flat-lis (flatten-list list)).

Comment: @Doesn't Matter: a part of the code in the function can be deleted, it is never used. The last clause in the COND will never be executed.

Comment: how can the second function be written using reduce and why the defvar and setf is not right?

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter Because `defvar` really only makes sense on the top-level. To bind a variable inside a function, use `let`. Since you're not setting any new values, the result-form of the let can be the value you need, so the `setf` is not needed.